# BGE and MakeHuman:Why the mesh is not displayed correctly?

Tags: mesh, texturing, game-engine, makehuman

Why the mesh is not displayed correctly in BGE, with or without clothes? Please see the picture and the blend file:
[Blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32783)

[image: Picture]

Comment: Can you replied the file with the textures? Without them, it's very hard to see what's wrong. You can upload all the textures with the Blend file by using 'File > External Data > Pack All into .Blend'

Comment: Mike I've updated the blend file, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the file is in great shape. All you had to do is set the Shading mode to **GLSL**. It's currently set to **Multitexture**, which is an older, and less powerful system.

[image]

As an aside, the purple texture you see is the normal map on the character, which isn't supported in Multitexture mode.